# Modelling a warehouse in optimization?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to model the following rather general optimization problem.

Let $p_{t}$ be a given non time series of product prices. These are fixed points $p_{t}$ is not described as a random variable. If you produce or have the product stored at time $t$, you may chosse to sell an arbitrary quantity of your stock and gain the current price $p_{t}$ as profit.

We have a machine, producing that product, that can run at most $h$ hours a day. Also we have a warehouse, that allows to store us up to $c$ hours of the machines output. For simplicity we assume that warehouse and machine costs are negligible.

We want to find the schedule for the machine that maximizes our profit.

In the case of $c=0$ the answer is clearly to produce on the $h$ hours of the day with maximal price.

How do i model the influence of the warehouse correctly?
What changes if $c$ increases? How do i adapt my scheme?

The question whetever something should be stored depends on all future prizes and seems therefore very hard to express. I suspect it might be a NP-hard problem of sorts, but i could not find any formulation of the problem, even though it seems very common.

Comment: Is $p_t$ known? Are there costs associated with running the machine or storing items in the warehouse?

Comment: @Math1000 p_{t} is known, it is not a random variable. In fact, the problem i am considering includes several more complicated cost effects, among them storage costs, as well as costs for start/stoping the machine and also the possibility to get more $h$ for a prize. I felt however that the question would be more clear without these effects, since i really wanted to understand the role of the warehouse. Let me know if you think they can not be disregarded, than it might be worthwile to edit the question.

Comment: Profit is revenue minus cost. Without knowing revenue or cost, how can we maximize profit?

Comment: This may help you get to a tractable problem formulation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_decision_process

Comment: @Math1000 The time series $p_{t}$ describes the possible revenue, if you can produce or have a stored product availible at time $t$ you add to the profit. For simplicity, i want to assume the cost of the storage to be negligible. Thus the profit is simply the revenue. Maybe i'll try to edit the question to make clear what i am after.

Comment: @Ben thank you, i think i should have stated stronger that i'm not considering a stochastic model. $p_{t}$ are known prices, thus a Markov model is not applicable. I'lL make this point more clear in the question.

Comment: Not trying to give you a hard time @ckrk, it's just that you really need to include as much relevant information as possible when developing a model :)

Comment: @Math1000 no of course! comments are very welcome! It's always hard to clearly state what is in your head, im happy if it gets feedback!

Comment: What about the demand?

Comment: @OccupyGezi The demand is only implicitly included in the model. Note that the we are given a fixed time series $p_{t}$ of prices. These can be seen as a description of the demand. In fact, choosing $p_{t}$ to be fixed, can be seen as an assumption that our company is small relative to the market. Fixing the price says we can always sell at market price, without influcencing the market price, because our company is small.

Comment: Actually I tried to ask about initial demand. Let's say the machine produced $X$ units in a day; how much is the max. amount that can be sold in the same day?

Comment: @OccupyGezi There is no limit on the demand. You could sell all you produce.